# Why do I need so many reputation points to create a comment?

Tags: support

Someone needs 50 reputation points to comment, but no points to create an answer... I don't understand this difference.

I have a similar problem than [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14834/sharepoint-site-accessing-using-different-port-and-alternate-accessing-mapping-p), and I want to make a comment explaining my case and it didn't work for me. What I should do? Should I make a new question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reasoning is... we want to encourage new users to post answers rather than comments.

You already have some reputation, so I think by answering/asking a couple questions you can reach the 50 rep requirement fairly quickly. :)

References:

- [Lower the amount of reputation needed to comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/lower-the-amount-of-reputation-needed-to-comment)
- [Lower commenting threshold to 1 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71390/146095)

Comment: That's what I was looking for, references. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As a relative newbie I sometimes find it hard without the ability to comment on the question to ask for clarification. Sometimes I feel that if I could ask for more information I might be able to answer it or help someone else answer the question.

A comment I frequently wish I could post is to ask which version of software they are using. Otherwise I could be posting an unrelevant answer

Comment: If you have an answer that may not be relevant, depending on a detail that's missing from the question, and you don't have the rep to comment, the best approach is to go ahead and post your answer, and attach a conditional statement. For example, "Although your question doesn't mention which version of the software you're running, I know that on version N you can do X. Note that this won't work in version F or earlier, and I'm not sure whether it works in versions Q and R." This way, even if the original poster is using version F, your answer can still help a later user who *is* on version N.